# Is there any way to print directly from the phone?

Tags: printing

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no" since printer manufacturers haven't yet started making drivers for Android (or iPhone).

I guess I'm just curious if anyone has heard anything about this and if/when it will become a reality.  (or perhaps if it already is, and I'm just oblivious to it?)

Comment: See also this other question [Is there a way to print from an Android tablet (preferably without a PC/cloud)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a great question.  I went looking for that functionality back in the spring but only found apps that would let you print to wifi enabled printers.

I just looked again and came across [PrinterShare](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.dynamixsoftware.printershare), which looks pretty cool.  Apparently you can print to a wifi printer, or with software installed on a local pc you can print over the internet to the attached printer.  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet and it looks a little pricey but seems promising.

Comment: +1 Printer Share works great!

Answer (score 10):

More of Google's products are now implementing the [Google Cloud Printing](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/04/new-approach-to-printing.html) service. Read more on that on the official google mobile blog: http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/01/cloud-printing-on-go.html

That might become an option to print from the Android phone in the coming months.

Answer (score 6):

There are several manufacturer independent solutions available as well, using different technologies:

- **Local Network:**

  - *Bluetooth:* [Bluetooth Smart Printing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.co.iconlab.BasicPrintingProfile)
    [image: Bluetooth Smart Printing]
  - *Other Networks:* [Let's Print Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackspruce.lpd) is mainly intended for network enabled Laser printers<sup>[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkfmR.jpg)</sup>, but also supports Google Cloud printing; [PrintBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.jsecurity.printbot) claims to support almost 3.000 printer models via Wifi; this is also the way [ePrint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.microtech.android.eprint)<sup>[9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJLx.jpg)</sup> (~ EUR 5) works
    [image: Let's Print Droid] [image]
- **Cloud:**

  - *PrinterOn Network:* Sit in Tokio, print in Chicago -- doesn't that rather sound like Fax? Nevermind, it gets printed on paper, so e.g.: [PrinterOn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.printeron.droid.phone)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqNTS.jpg)</sup>; quite comparable with the Breezy network, e.g. [Breezy - Print and Fax](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.breezy.android)<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEwzb.jpg)</sup>
    [image: PrinterOn] [image: Breezy]
  - *Google Cloud printing:* e.g. [Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pauloslf.cloudprint)<sup>[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSfGz.jpg)</sup>, [Easy Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipdog.easyprint)<sup>[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov9tG.jpg)</sup>
    [image: Cloud Print] [image: Easy Print]
  - *Wifi, 3G, 4G:* [FileLinx 3G Print or Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stl.file_transfer)<sup>[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTZ4J.jpg)</sup> (~ EUR 5), [Print from Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mlc.print)<sup>[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNKnl.jpg)</sup> (~ EUR 1) -- both require free PC software
    [image: FileLinx] [image: Print from Android]

These all are just examples for their corresponding "types" -- checking in the Playstore you will find many more. Also, several others have already be mentioned -- such as [manufacturer dependant solutions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/8751/16575) or [PrinterShare](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1433/16575).

Answer (score 1):

At least one manufacturer has tried to address this issue with an Andoid app. Samsung has an app named Samsung MobilePrint that works for Samsung wireless and networked printers.

[Samsung MobilePrint](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sec.print.mobileprint)

Only Samsung branded printers supported.

Comment: Adding to this, there's also [Epson iPrint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=epson.print), [HP ePrint Home & Biz](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.print), [Brother iPrint&Scan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brother.mfc.brprint), [KODAK Document Print App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kodak.view), [Canon Easy-PhotoPrint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.canon.bsd.android.aepp.activity), [Lexmark Mobile Printing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexmark.print)...

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea of needing drivers suggested by the OP needs clarifying. The way I believe things are is that a) if you were trying to communicate directly to a printer, yes you need a driver but b) if you were communicating with a printer say on a LAN server, whether the driver on the LAN can do that job. The task (at least IMO, although apps seem to differ) can become more one of asking the server what a printer can or can not do. There is scope for variations (eg, converting or interpretation of document format within this.,,

My own attempt at an app follows plan b (which does require a computer to be on and an Internet route ). From that, I can even send a job to a CD without needing a driver installed on the Android as the CUPs (in this case) server knows how to tell the printer to do these things.

I perhaps should also mention "wifi enabled". If you are going a Cups route, I think the physical location of the printers dictates whether you want to reach them via a network (The Android just has to reach the Cups server) Neither of the printers at home are. At home, there are two printers.  The Laser printer is a Xerox Phaser 6110N. This is a hard wired LAN printer. Our Epson P50 connects via an old (and I believe long discontinued Belkin print sharing device). When our previous Epson R220 died, I did consider a photo printer in their range that had got built it wifi and would have preferred to have disposed of the Belkin device.  I decided against as there was a fair step in price to do this