# How can I print web pages from my Android to a wireless Printer?

Tags: printing

There is a system I log into online that generates web pages for a printing. This works great on the PC using Chrome, Firefox and IE.

I would like a way to print these web pages from the tablet (Galaxy 2, Android 4). Unfortunately, these web pages I am referring to require me to be logged in. Many print apps I have found simply re-visit the URL without using my login credentials. That will not work for me.

The best solution I have found was to use Firefox's save PDF feature, then open the PDF with the Cloud Print app, which would then print to my PC or one of the [Google Cloud ready printers](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html).

Ideally it would connect using WiFi or Bluetooth, but the Cloud Print over Internet idea is good enough for now.

- Unfortunately it takes 7 clicks at this point (menu -> tools -> save pdf -> open status bar -> open the pdf (at this point Cloud Print is set as default) -> click print (with default printer) -> click back to go back)
- Not to mention, there will be many pdf files just sitting on the phone that should eventually be cleaned up.

Can you recommend a better solution?

Comment: Way too many questions in one post. I'd strongly suggest to split them up, starting with the basics first, and then asking additional questions *separately* when needed. This is a Q&A site -- which means: One question plus its answers belong together on one page. The first item of your list is more than enough for a question. Chances of answers increase dramatically if you edit your question and remove the other items for now.

Comment: Edited. Is this better?

Comment: Did you look at any of the other questions tagged [tag:printing]? This is likely a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: @AlEverett right idea -- but take a look at his 2nd paragraph: with the location being password-protected, most of the "standard solutions" (cloud printing etc.) might fail. Still, there might as well be some questions already addressing that.

Comment: With e.g. [Is there a way to print from an Android tablet (preferably without a PC/cloud)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17294/16575) your problem might be reduced to "How to open a PDF directly from behind a password-protected URL"...