# Is it possible to directly print from Android?

Tags: printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any way to print directly from the phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/is-there-any-way-to-print-directly-from-the-phone)

Why can't Android devices directly print to a shared network printer? Or is there a way?

Comment: What kind of printer set up do you mean, exactly? My devices can print to my wireless printer, I just need an app for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible! Maybe not in the conventional way, but the easiest way would be to set it up as a [Google Cloud Printer](http://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/) and download the [Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint) app.

Also,

> if you have an Cloudprint ready printer (Epson, Kodak etc) or HP
>   E-Print enabled printer you don't need your pc to be on, for other
>   printers your pc needs to be ON.

So you might not be able to simply find a printer on your network natively in Android, but [Google](http://www.google.com) has provided us with the next best thing.

Comment: Isn't cloudprint only working on Windows-connected printers yet? Also, every cloudprint solution has security drawbacks. The provider sees every printjob which most people seem to forget nowadays. For companies this is definitely a no-go. Someone might also not like to transmit personal documents through the cloud.

Comment: OS wasn't expressed as a constraint here, and no, `Google Cloud Print can also connect to existing (classic) printers that are plugged into a Windows, Mac, or Linux computer with Internet access` ([source](http://support.google.com/cloudprint/?p=mkt_support_faq&hl=en#2541639)). And print job visibility wasn't listed as a stipulation either, was it?

Comment: I just wanted to point out the privacy issues. I had looked at this already but every printing solution back then did it in the cloud and seemingly still does. Regarding OS support: It just requires Chrome (and a Google account). There's also a python implementatiom for non GUI boxes thats available here https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint .

Comment: Am I missing something? How is cloudprint classed as "direct"?

Comment: @jlehenbauer The wording is confusing because you say no but then you say can. However, Linux and Mac can https://github.com/google/cups-connector You just need to install a cups compatible print app on android.