# How to print a webpage from my Android phone?

Tags: printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to print directly from the phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/is-there-any-way-to-print-directly-from-the-phone)

Assuming a modern (compatible) **mobile** printer, is it possible to print a webpage or a PDF document directly and **natively** from the phone?

I've heard of **[PrintShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare)**, and saw **[this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/is-there-any-way-to-print-directly-from-the-phone)**, I'm asking if it can be done natively, without the use of another application.

If that's not possible, is there some sort of API I can use to achieve it? Assuming I write my own application.

Comment: I have casted close vote because its off-topic. No development questions, please.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: This isn't necessarily a development question, I'm asking whether it's possible to print a webpage or a PDF document, whether programmatically or not.

Comment: Questions from the perspective of developers are also off-topic here.

Comment: @Truth Since you mentioned the duplicate question of this one, I wonder what makes your question different then the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

There is no known API available for any form of printing support within the Android system itself.